# How to work with non required JSON parameters in Go?

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Hi I am working on a rest API in Go and I want the user to pass JSON parameters:

```
Offset int64  `json:"offset"`
Limit  int64  `json:"limit"`
SortBy string `json:"sortby"`
Asc    bool   `json:"asc"`
Username   string `json:"username"`
First_Name string `json:"first_name"`
Last_Name  string `json:"last_name"`
Status     string `json:"status"`
```

But they are not always required so for example a user can pass only `Offset` and ignore the others. He can even send 0 parameters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When unmarshalling a value from JSON text, the [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package does not require that all fields to be present in JSON, nor that all JSON fields have a matching Go field.

So you don't have anything special to do, just unmarshal what you have to a Go value what you want or may want.

One thing to note is that if a field is missing in the JSON text, the `json` package will not change the corresponding Go field, so if you start with a "fresh", [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), the field will be left with the zero value of its type.

Most of the time this is enough to detect the presence or absence of a field (in JSON), for example if in the Go struct you have a `SortBy` field of type `string`, if this is missing in JSON, it will remain the empty `string`: `""`.

If the zero value is something useful and valid, then you may turn to use pointers. For example if in your application the empty `string` would be a valid `SortBy` value, you may declare this field to be a pointer: `*string`. And in this case if it's missing in the JSON text, it will remain `nil`, the zero value for any pointer type.

See this example:

```
type Data struct {
    I int
    S string
    P *string
}

func main() {
    var d Data
    var err error

    d, err = Data{}, nil
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"I":1, "S":"sv", "P":"pv"}`), &d)
    fmt.Printf("%#v %v\n", d, err)

    d, err = Data{}, nil
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"I":1}`), &d)
    fmt.Printf("%#v %v\n", d, err)

    d, err = Data{}, nil
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"S":"abc"}`), &d)
    fmt.Printf("%#v %v\n", d, err)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vszUWmqZTf)):

```
main.Data{I:1, S:"sv", P:(*string)(0x1050a150)} <nil>
main.Data{I:1, S:"", P:(*string)(nil)} <nil>
main.Data{I:0, S:"abc", P:(*string)(nil)} <nil>
```